# Attaching (or not) .mdf file to SQLEXPRESS 17 using connString

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-express

I'm working on deploying my software using Advanced Installer and I want to attach the .mdf file located in the [APPDIR] (client pc's destination folder). I came across this connection string:

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

This will attach with no problem when my app runs but, after its done, it will pop up an error "database mydbfile already exists, choose a diferent name" every other time the app is opened. In the description it says: "If the named database have already been attached, SQL Server does not reattach it. It uses the attached database as the default for the connection." But its not happening as its trying to attach it every single time.

Comment: If the server already has the mdf attached, or another instance of the Server has file attached you cannot attach again.  The attach in the connection string is not needed.  If you need a mdf file permanently attached do it through a SQL Command and not through the connection string.

Comment: To clarify, what I need is to attach it the first time the program is run, but after that just use the already attached db. Problem is I dont know how code that, as it needs to be automatic and not require manual interaction. Could you please tell me how to do that with a SQL Command? detect the APPDIR where my soft was installed and use it to grab the mdf and attach it?

Comment: GetSchema will give all items attached to database.  You could also just do a select * query and when nothing is returned do the attach.  Or even have a stored procedure.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is can be done by leveraging [SQL Server Express User Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances)

First, connect to your SQL Express instance using SQL Server Management Studio and manually detach the database. Then, update the connection string to include `User Instance=true;`